# Cisco IP Phone Call Manager handle events

Tags: events, phone-call, cisco

I'm new on cisco IP Phones.
I have a cisco call manager system also a 7970 Ip phone.
The phone cominicates with Cisco Call Manager application.
I want to listen events when user logon and send some commands to phone.,
Is there any idea about this task?
Is there a way to got events from cisco call manager or I have to listen up the ports of IP phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the phone registered as SIP phone or SCCP phone .
Traces from the call manager are the best way of finding out what is happening in the sytem.
You can also look for packet captures on the phone in those captures you can see SCCP events and SIP events 
for example you can see events like 
SIP INVITE , OK , BYE..etc.

apart from this call manager traces SDI and SDL traces for "call manager service" will give you whole lot of information you need.
This link will help you take traces in call manager:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/voicesw/ps556/products_tech_note09186a0080094e89.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Cisco JTAPI is the best API to perform 3rd party call control and get events about IP phone state. You'll write an application in Java that uses the Cisco JTAPI jar. This api will let you subscribe to a specific phone and you'll be able to get events like OnHook, OffHook, Connected, Disconnected, etc.

JTAPI is fairly complicated. Cisco has a product called Cisco Unified Application Environment that can help simplify the development task. It isn't free, however.

Comment: Thanks for your post..I will search on JTAPI also..for now I used ExtensionMobility to check if any user logged on phone...